# KDE: How to add a shortcut to an executable file to the favourites menu with command line?

Tags: kde

I know how to do it with the GUI. 
But I need to do it with the command line. I found no solution by using google. There were only solution by using the GUI.

It is about the favourite tab in the application launcher.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the favourites tab in the Kickoff launcher. After adding a program to it, I can see `~/.config/kactivitymanagerd-statsrc` being modified. However, any changes in the text file followed by restarting plasmashell makes no difference.

Comment: Yes exactly. It is about the fav tab in the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to edit `~/.config/kactivitymanagerd-statsrc` file?

And a tip, never edit manually your Plasma config files when you're in a Plasma session. This is because Plasma overwrites any manual changes in your config files when you end your session.